# How to drive 128 LEDs

Tags: led

I now have a PCB with 64 UV LEDs on it and I use this to expose other PCBs. I have a serial resistor for each LED which produces a lot of heat and consumes about 1.3 A at 12 V.

I am now considering to make a bigger UV unit with twice the size of my current UV unit. I have searched on the internet how to drive this amount of LEDs but the only things I came across where ways to drive each LED individually.

I was thinking to make groups of LEDs (5 by example) and use one resister for each group of LEDs.

Are any other efficient ways to drive 128 LEDs without grouping the LEDs?

Comment: Do you have a schematic? It would help to know the characteristics of your LEDs and how they are "grouped."

Comment: Forward Voltage: 3.2 V - 3.8 V, Forward Current : 20mA.

Comment: I think @Ale pretty much nailed it. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most efficient way to drive such a big number of LEDs will probably be to use a constant current generator (there are many ICs for that, many dedicated to LED applications, as for example the AP8800, which is a 350 mA converter for LEDs — this is a fairly standard current value for LED lighting applications, what current do you actually need for your UV LEDs?), and then connect the LEDs in series as strips of (for example) 8, each strip having its own constant current generator. Of course you will need to power the board with a relatively high voltage (e.g., 24V), but this should generally not be a problem.

A very simple solution for your 20 mA, 3.8V LEDs could be a linear constant current regulator like the CL520 (a small transistor-like device, which only takes an external 100 nF capacitor to work), or a constant current diode, like the NSI45020T1G: if you take a standard 48V power supply, one CL520 could handle 12 LEDs in series (the NSI45020T1G is limited to 45V). If the LEDs have the highest VF, with 48V input and 12 LEDs (total VF = 45.6 V) the regulator has to dissipate 48 mW, which would only lead to temperature increase of around 6 °C with the small TO-92 package. If the LEDs have the lowest VF (total VF = 38.4 V), the total dissipation would be 192 mW, with a temperature increase around 25 °C (which is still acceptable). For LEDs with higher currents, however, such devices that just dissipate the excess voltage as heat would heat up way too much, that's why devices like the AP8800 are implemented as switching step-down converters (using a coil).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using your existing 12V power supply then you can only group your LEDs in 2's or 3's.

3's would be more efficient, and each group of 3 would then need a 75 ohm resistor.
This resistor should not get noticeably warm (since its only dropping about 1.5V now instead of 8.5V) - a 1/4W rated resistor should work just fine here.

You could make groups of 2 if you wanted to (and even mix them up with groups of 3). For 2's you would need a 240 ohm resistor for each group and although a 1/4W rated resistor would also work here, you might notice it getting a little warm.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an inexpensive [36V supply](http://www.ebay.com/itm/36V-1-5A-Universal-Regulated-Switching-Power-Supply-60W-/230759903468?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35ba5cb0ec) and group the LEDs in 8's. Then you'd need only 16 small resistors. If you are running the LEDs at 20mA, the total current would be 320mA or about 12W total power @36V.

"UV" LEDs have quite high forward voltage so thermal issues are important to consider. You may wish to run them at somewhat less than maximum current for longevity reasons. If you put the resistors into two DIP-16 plug headers you could change them all at once (in two groups).

Answer (score 2):

Why not power 135 LEDS - 5 strings of 27 LEDs - directly off the mains as shown below?

With 120 volt mains, a nominal 3.6 volts across each LED, and an 1100 ohm ballast in each string, each resistor will dissipate about 576 milliwatts.

For the bridge, about 100mA through two diodes at a time with about 1.5 volts dropped across the pair equals about 150 milliwatts, so the whole thing dissipates just over 3 watts.

The Zener TVS's  are in there - as insurance - to absorb any spikes from the mains, and normally draw no current.

[image]

Comment: the idea is interesting, just the LEDs would probably visibly flicker at the mains frequency (which is probably ok for that application). in case the circuit has to be powered with 230V and not 120V, then it would have to be adapted for that voltage adding more LEDs in the chains.

Comment: Flicker at 120 Hz will not be visible.  If it were important for some reason, a modest capacitor at the DC rail would reduce the flicker (and is a good idea anyway to reduce the peak-to-average power ratio)

Comment: Flicker of an ultraviolet light at any frequency will not be visible ;-) (yes I know UV LEDs actually emit some visible light too...)

Comment: ...also, the obvious answer to 'why not...' is safety - it's certainly *possible* to construct and use the above circuit safely, but this requires an understanding of the proper construction techniques which we can't guarantee that the OP has. I'd want to see a fuse on the live input for a start.

Comment: At least at my place the voltage over the day is not constant can fluctuate in the percent level. Therefore also the light will undergo this flucutations.

Comment: @EMFields: you're right, I didn't take into account that it is a full-wave rectifier. Besides that, I often notice the 100 Hz flickering in some LED lights (as mains here in Europe is 50 Hz) and find that particularly annoying. However, as the UV source is not going to be used for room lighting, it's less a problem...

Comment: @pericynthion: What do you mean by "reduce the peak-to-average power ratio?

Comment: @nekomatic: Just like we can't guarantee that the OP has the skills necessary to keep himself alive around 240V mains, neither can we guarantee that he doesn't, and mere conjecture is hardly a sound basis for admonition.

Comment: Is the "invisible" flicker effect going to affect the quality of PCB exposure?

Comment: I can't imagine why, since all you have to do is leave the lamp on long enough to make sure the resist is fully developed, and I think you've got enough leeway on the "too long" end for it to matter much.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to power something that consumes significant power and has specific voltage requirements, it is difficult to beat the efficiency of a switching supply. You could use one of those cheap step-down DC converters that are like $10 USD for 10 on Ebay. One could probably supply 1.3A just fine with a heat sink but I would just split up the load into smaller arrays that consume at most 1A each. They have trimmers on them to adjust the voltage which could easily be replaced with a potentiometer with a knob. Then you can have a small ballast resistor and adjust the voltage until the LED array reached the desired brightness. Then the voltage drop across the resistors would be small and thus they would put out low heat. The switching frequency of those DC converters is like 60KHz so you would not see any flicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can drive LEDs without any series resistor at all if you control them with PWM. The datasheet for your LEDs will specify a maximum continuous current, and also a maximum pulsed current and how long they can tolerate that current. Combine those numbers with the maximum current your power source can drive (if it's a higher voltage, maybe put some in series—we can be reasonable) and you might find a frequency and a duty cycle that can drive your LEDs with much less waste heat. You might even stagger or Charlieplex them if you want to be nicer to your power supply.

I haven't done this, though I've given it quite a bit of thought. To back me up, here's a page of someone who did try, though it looks like he didn't get to following up: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/led-without-resistor/.

Comment: LEDs are non-linear components, so a tiny change in the voltage can lead to a tiny or huge change on the current, depending on the actual voltage level... operating the LEDs near their nominal current without a resistor (or another way to control the current) will possibly shorten their life if the input voltage is not stable enough, as they can be easily exposed to higher average currents than specified by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way of driving large numbers of LEDs is in chains and with a current limiting resistor. This is your easiest way and if you aren't overly fussed about matching the brightness in each chain, you can do this direct from your power supply (I would try this first).

The trick is to work out what current you are going to drive the LEDs at and look up or measure the forward voltage drop of an LED. There will be a certain tolerance so you will need a margin in there. Then add up how many you can fit into your power supply. So if you had a 12V supply and your LEDs with 3V then rather than string 4 together, go for 3 to leave some headroom. Whatever voltage is left is what get dropped across your resistor which you size the wattage accordingly.

You want the least amount of spare voltage left over the resistor, so if you can tweak the power supply up or down, so that you get a good number of LEDs vs resistor voltage drop, that's your optimum point. This will minimise the amount of heat wasted across the resistor.

In advanced LEDs linear lighting, they use DC-DC converters to drive the top voltage with constant current chain drivers to dynamically optimise this.